# Ошибка 403 при запуске приложения

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vkontakte-api, deploy

Началось все после деплоя думаю, но именно случилось не понимаю.
Вот ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А иногда выходит такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я только учусь, поэтому не понимаю как решать такие баги

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "mini-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env PORT=10888 HTTPS=true react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "vk-miniapps-deploy"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.0.0"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@vkontakte/icons": "1.141.1",
    "@vkontakte/vk-bridge": "latest",
    "@vkontakte/vk-miniapps-deploy": "0.0.25",
    "@vkontakte/vkjs": "0.20.0",
    "@vkontakte/vkui": "4.28.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eruda": "^2.4.1",
    "eruda-code": "^2.0.0",
    "eruda-dom": "^2.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "recoil": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.13.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-scripts/webpack-dev-server/yargs/yargs-parser": ">=18.1.2"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "es5-ext@^0.10.50": "0.10.53"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сервис, к которому идет запрос по url отвечает вам ошибкой 403 (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_403),
означающий, что доступ к запрошенному ресурсу запрещен. Сервер понял запрос, но не выполнит его. вам нужно разбираться правильно ли вы делаете запрос и туда ли. Так же можете показать код запросов которые вызывают ошибку, и название сервисов(или библиотек) которые используете, может тут найдутся люди которые работали с этим.